# Sort array size

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a hyperlink of various worksheets on a table of contents using visual basic.

The first sheet is the table of contents. The worksheets to be included in the table of contents therefore start at worksheet2. I am unablet to change the array to begin at worksheet 2.

These are my lines of code

```
'Create Table of Contents

 ' Create array with locations

    Set firstsheet = Worksheet(2).Value

    '  Dim arrworksheets(2 To Worksheets.Count) As Long

    For x = arr(firstsheet) To UBound(myArray)

    Set sht = Worksheets(myArray(x))

    sht.Activate

    With Content_sht

      .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x + 2, 3), "", _

      SubAddress:="'" & sht.Name & "'!A1", _

      TextToDisplay:=sht.Name

      .Cells(x + 2, 2).Value = x

    End With

  Next x
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What is your actual question? What's not working?

Comment: The array does not begin at worksheet 2

Comment: This line makes no sense `Set firstsheet = Worksheet(2).Value`. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: What's the name of the first sheet ( table of contents)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are wanting to iterate through all the sheets in your workbook, but excluding the first sheet in the list - the contents page.

There's a great example of how to achieve this [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/3/28/automate-building-table-of-contents-spreadsheet-with-vba), which judging by the similarity in your code, you may have already had a peek at.

The relevant part you want to look at is:

```
'Create Array list with sheet names (excluding Contents)
  ReDim myArray(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1)

  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> ContentName Then
      myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next sht
```

Here, instead of trying to exclude the  contents page based on it's order in the workbook, it excludes it based on the sheet name - `If sht.Name <> ContentName`.

However for completeness, if you still want to do this based on the position that each sheet is in, you can simply use a For loop instead of an array and begin at 2 (remember, sheet collections are not 0-base indexed):

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim Content_sht As Worksheet
Dim sht_nam As String

count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
Set Content_sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'whatever your contents page is called


For x = 2 To count

    sht_nam = Worksheets(x).Name

    With Content_sht
      .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x + 2, 3), "", _
      SubAddress:="'" & sht_nam & "'!A1", _
      TextToDisplay:=sht_nam
      .Cells(x + 2, 2).Value = x
    End With

Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MakeTOC()    'Create Table of Contents
    Const TOC_COL = 3
    Const TOC_ROW = 5
    Dim wsTOC As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, nextRow As Long, linkAddress As String

    Set wsTOC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")   'TOC Sheet

    With wsTOC.Cells(TOC_ROW - 2, TOC_COL)  'Set title cell
        .Value2 = "Table of Contents"
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    nextRow = TOC_ROW

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  'Add list of Sheet Names
        If ws.Name <> wsTOC.Name Then
            linkAddress = "'" & ws.Name & "'!A1"
            With wsTOC.Cells(nextRow, TOC_COL)
                .Value2 = ws.Name
                .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(1), vbNullString, SubAddress:=linkAddress, _
                                TextToDisplay:=ws.Name
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Offset(, -1) = nextRow - TOC_ROW + 1
                .Offset(, -1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            nextRow = nextRow + 1
        End If
    Next
    wsTOC.Columns(TOC_COL).Columns.AutoFit
    wsTOC.UsedRange.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

---

Output

[image: Result]