# Create Hyperlink using Sheet Number

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create hyperlink that will link to different sheets through vba. In my workbook Sheet Name is given as "Stock Code 1", "Stock Code 2" and so on. I want to create hyperlink on a sheet namely "Index Page" in the same workbook but the condition is hyperlink will start after last used row in column "M" (Used columns are already hyperlinked to its sheet) and sheet name will be displayed as number like for "Stock Code 1000" it will display as 1000

Example:

Hyperlink Required for: "Stock Code 1001 to Stock Code 1010"
Last Used Column: M1000
Hyperlink Start from: M1001 to M1010
Hyperlink Data: 1001 to 1010

I've a following code of inserting new sheets to my workbook. Is there any tricks to create hyperlinks to those new sheets within it?

```
Sub InsertSheets()
Dim numSheets As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim lastName As String
Dim lastNum As Long

' Find name of last sheet
lastName = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name

' Get last number from name
lastNum = Mid(lastName, InStrRev(lastName, " ") + 1) + 0

' Ask for how many sheets to create
numSheets = Application.InputBox("How many sheets do you want to insert?")

' If they entered a number greater than 0, Add sheets

If numSheets >= 1 Then
For i = (lastNum + 1) To (lastNum + numSheets)
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Stock Code " & i

Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Help required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the InputBox you may want to validate user input - what if they enter "abc", or 999999999, or 1/0 ?

Comment: This may help: [Creating a Table of Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917893/sort-array-size/49924040#49924040)

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you would use a hyperlinks object collection. (See referance here: [Hyperlinks.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel) )

Here are some links that will ***help you with hyperlinks in Excel***:

1. First **manually** so you get how to add hyperlinks:
    [How to add a hyperlink to another sheet](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/15/excel-insert-hyperlink/)
2. Then how to do that with **VBA**:
   [Add Hyperlinks in Excel using VBA](http://www.encodedna.com/excel/how-to-add-and-find-hyperlinks-in-excel-using-vba-macro.htm)
   [Hyperlinks in Excel VBA – Explained with Examples!](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/hyperlinks-examples/)

You will also need to know:

- [How to Find the Last Row, Column, or Cell on a Sheet](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/)

And how to reference that as an object:

- [Referring to Cells by Using a Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221547(v=office.11).aspx)

  ```
  Sub InsertSheets()
      Dim lastName As String
      Dim lastNum As Long
      Dim numSheets As Integer
      Dim i As Long
      Dim linkEntryRow As Long

      ' Find name of last sheet
      lastName = Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Name

      ' Get last number from name
      lastNum = Mid(lastName, InStrRev(lastName, " ") + 1) + 0

      ' Ask for how many sheets to create
      numSheets = Application.InputBox("How many sheets do you want to insert?")

      ' If they entered a number greater than 0, Add sheets
      If numSheets >= 1 Then
          For i = (lastNum + 1) To (lastNum + numSheets)
              'Find the last non-blank cell in column M (column 13) and go to the next row for a blank cell.
              linkEntryRow = Worksheets("Index Page").Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
              Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1)
              ActiveSheet.Name = "Stock Code " & i
              ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Worksheets("Index Page").Range("M" & CStr(linkEntryRow)), _
                  Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name &         "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=CStr(i)
          Next i
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you found the response helpful, kindly vote it up. If it answers your question, say thank you by marking it as the answer. Glad to help, pass it on.